# Retrieve firstparentonly on master using libgit2sharp

Tags: libgit2sharp

I want to retrieve commits from master first parent only using libgit2sharp, the equivalent command line statement is

> git log --first-parent master --oneline

I know of the CommitFilter that I can use with QueryBy, like this

> repo.Commits.QueryBy(new CommitFilter() { FirstParentOnly = true  })

I'm getting commits on the branch that I'm currently on if I'm not on master.  Can I limit the commit results to master, even when I'm on a different branch ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the `IncludeReachableFrom` in the `CommitFilter`.

You might want to also use `ExcludeReachableFrom` at the same time to remove the commits from the branch that you are currently on...

```
using (var repo = new Repository("/Users/sushi/code/redux/playscript"))
{
    var commitLog = repo.Commits.QueryBy(new CommitFilter() { FirstParentOnly = true, IncludeReachableFrom = "master" });
    foreach (var commit in commitLog)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{commit.Sha}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```